# Solving estimating equation using R

Tags: r, computational-statistics, generalized-estimating-equations

I am working with different types of data and comparing a variety of estimating equation approaches which share a multi-dimensional parameter $\beta$. Given a set of data $\boldsymbol{X}$, is there an easy way to solve for $\beta$ numerically using R code for an estimating equation of the form: $$U(\boldsymbol{X}, \beta) = 0?$$
I am aware of the function `uniroot` in one-dimension but how can it be extended to say two or three dimensions?

Comment: What is $U$?  Is it the score function?

Comment: A general equation but not necessarily something that is a score function. For example, it could be represent a generalized estimating equation or it could represent an equation based on the ranks of the observed data. I am concerned with how the roots are computed in R.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your function it is difficult to offer an optimal solution.  However, one approach is to use a general nonlinear optimisation routine to minimise the quantity:

$$L(\beta) \equiv U(\mathbf{X}, \beta)^2.$$

You can use the [`nlm` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nlm.html) in `R` to undertake nonlinear minimisation of this objective function, including in cases with a vector parameter.  This function also allows you to specify a relevant gradient vector and Hessian matrix if you have analytic results for these (of you can leave them out and `R` will estimate them numerically).  I often use this method when dealing with cases like this in `R` and it usually works quite well.  For best performance I recommend using appropriate parameter transforms (if needed) to ensure that you are doing unconstrained optimisation with the `nlm` function.